# Method Reference Using An Interface (Implemented By More Than One Class) As A Type

Tags: java, interface, method-reference

```
public interface Intf {
int size();
}

public class Cls1 implements Intf {
public int size() {
// implementation 1
}

public class Cls2 implements Intf {
public int size() {
// implementation 2
}
```

Now, which of the above two implementations will the following method reference refer to ?

```
Intf::size // note: using Intf
```

On what basis will the compiler choose between the above two? Or will this method reference throw an exception ?

Comment: Why do you think, the compiler would choose between the two classes `Cls1` or `Cls2` when you write `Intf::size`, which doesn’t refer to any of them? If you think the compiler chose an arbitrary implementation class, why not `Cls3`?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way that polymorphism works in general.

That is, the same way that if you have an `intf1 someObject`, you can call `someObject.instanceMethodName()` and it works.

This is no different for method references than any other kind of method invocation.

Comment: Please have another look at the final part of my question. I am assuming that  'instanceMethodName' exists in multiple classes that implement 'intf1'. So, having no class name mentioned in the method reference (only the intf1) , how can the compiler decide which class is the one?

Comment: You mean, `instanceMethodName` is not a method on the interface?  If it is a method on the interface...then my answer still answers your question.  This is exactly how polymorphism normally works.  If it's not on the interface, then there's no way to do it not even with method references.

Comment: Definitely it is on the interface, but as an abstract method. And it has different implementations in multiple classes. So, again, which class is the one? (in other words, if call using an object, then there is no problem. But we are calling using the interface).

Comment: No, there's still no problem calling it using the interface. You don't _need_ to know which class to reference, you just call it from the interface.

Comment: If you have an object of an interface type, you can always call that method on the object.  Period.  There is zero difference here between method references and other method invocations.

Comment: I know. But again, which version of implementation will the compiler choose? ... we have different implementations for that method in multiple classes. I hope you get my point.

Comment: `intf1::instanceMethodName` creates a lambda which accepts an object of type `intf1`.  It will choose whichever implementation is tied to the actual runtime class of the object you pass into it.  If you do `Function<intf1, Foo> something = intf1::instanceMethodName`, and you do `something.apply(bar)`, it'll call `bar.instanceMethodName()`.  Whatever the implementation of `bar.instanceMethodName()` is, is what it'll call.

Comment: It's _not choosing an implementation._  The implementation is chosen when you _use_ the method reference and pass in an implementation of `intf1`.

Comment: I have edited my question above, to better explain my point. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @basheer, it _does not choose between them._  `Intf::size` returns a functional interface type that accepts an `Intf` and returns an `int`.  If you pass it an instance of `Cls1` it will call `Cls1.size()`.  If you pass it an instance of `Cls2` it will call `Cls2.size()`.

Comment: Here's an example run in real code.  http://ideone.com/AcjUPa  `Intf::size` _doesn't choose_, you choose when you _use_ the method reference.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no implementation selection in case you described (and it's a good thing, neither compiler nor interpreter can make that decision), because inferrable type of

```
Intf::size
```

is actually a

```
Function<? extends Intf, Integer>
```

or

```
ObjToIntFunction<? extends Intf> // considering that return type is primitive int
```

Which means that you create lambda that accepts a single instance assignable to `Intf` type and returns an integer number.

Now, if you say

```
new Cls1()::size
```

then you will produce an `IntSupplier`, or `Supplier<Integer>`, whichever's better suited. Suppliers being methods that accept no argument, require you to make implementation selection yourself.